# jQuery ajax loading html / php content from external files

Tags: php, ajax

I have a mixed html / php in external files and loading that content dynamically:

example file: my_data.php

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="cell_inner">
        <label><?php esc_html_e('Player height:', AWP_TEXTDOMAIN); ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="cell_inner">
        <input type="number" class="playerHeight">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am retrieving this content in file with ajax:

php function:

```
function preview_preset_settings() {

        $result = dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/preset_config/ . 'my_data.php';
                
        $content = file_get_contents($result);
        
        header( "Content-Type: text/html" );

        echo $content;

        exit;
        
    }
```

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        data: ajax_data,
    }).done(function(result) {
    
        activePreset.empty().html(result);

 ....
```

The problem is when this comes back with ajax and I add this in my div container (activePreset.empty().html(result);), php tags are commented out.

So there is no result of

```
 <label><?php esc_html_e('Player height:', AWP_TEXTDOMAIN); ?></label>
```

As you can see I need to echo some php in there as well.

If this is not possible to achieve in such way I will have to take a different approach.

Comment: $content = require dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/preset_config/ . 'my_data.php', no need for file_get_contents

Comment: Does `esc_html_e` output any content? Is there an echo statement or print etc?

Comment: When you load the external file through AJAX, the source code should get loaded...the PHP code would not get executed at all....what are you trying to achieve with this call?

Comment: I can see php gets comments so its not visible like this:  <!--?php esc_html_e('Player height:', AWP_TEXTDOMAIN); ?-->   I am doing this because I have different content for different cases so I wanted it to be dynamic. If I place this directly in the page of course it works.